# Filter views by field value equals another field of curent node

Tags: views, 9

D9.3. All fields are not referenced, they are just simple integers. All data was pulled from a huge external API and it was not possible to create all references.

Just for ease of understanding, imagine a book database website with books and characters. But each character is presented in one book only.

So, book node has `field_book_id`, which is numeric, unique, but not NID. Also it has a multiple `field_character_ids` with a list of ids of all characters in this book.

A character node has its own `field_character_id` (matching with `field_character_ids` from book node). And also `field_my_book_id`, which equals to book id field.

**The goal is to create a View, which will show the current book's characters in a list.**

I'm using `Views Contextual Filter Default Entity Field Values` module which allows to pull fields values from the current node, for example.

But in Views Filter Criteria I can't match the selected field with the value from the Contextual Filter. It has only pre-defined operators, such as *is equal to, is less than, is greater than*, etc. And I can't select something like "Match value from contextual filter". I tried to use twig and replacement patterns there without any luck.

It would be a very simple database query, but is it possible to get it working in Views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was rather simple.

In contextual filter add the field you want to target.

Then: When the filter value is NOT available > Provide default value > Field value from current entity > under Entity Field select field which will filter the view results.